# AWS RDS. How to copy/move/migrate Parameters/options groups vetween aws accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I have a lot of parameters options groups in RDS service. So, how can I copy it between AWS accounts?

I didn't find any aws cli commands for it, so may be there is some third-party solutions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest option would be to use an SQL connector. You can easily download the schema file of an SQL database and then spin up an identical database from that schema file.

I've migrated local databases onto AWS and vice versa, I've even carried out cross-cloud migrations by this process.

Answer (score 0):

One option I think might work is import the Param group using Terraform, and then use the Terraform scripts to create the new ones.

I am guessing same might be possible with AWS cli. I am about to try it.